# Is there any advantage in wrapping a jasmine test in an IIFE?

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I am trying to get some coding standards setup for a new project and someone asked me why we don't wrap our jasmine tests in a IIFE when we wrap all over JavaScript in one.

I realized I actually have no idea and I don't think I have ever seen any examples on the internet using one.
So are there any advantages in using one? Is this something we should adapt?

Comment: Instead of answering "why don't you" ask them " why should we".

Comment: An IIFE is there to introduce scope or to close over a value which may otherwise be modified. Is there any need to do any of these things in your scenario...?